# Autofill other fields automatically if one field is entered with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please check my fiddle.

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjrddzo3/)

When i enter any data in any rows in slab_range, i need to autofill all the other rows of 'Slab Range' with a value 'No Bid'. If i left blank, nothing has to be filled. Likewise if i enter any data in 'Part Number', all the other rows of 'Part Number' has to be filled with value '2'. The rows are coming from db, so i cant tell how many rows it will be, it should iterate all the rows.

```
    <tr>
    <td>
   <input size="1" id="sl[0]" name="sl[0]" value="1" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input size="9" data-validation="required" name="slab_range[]" id="slab_range[]" type="text">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input size="9" name="item_partno[]" id="item_partno[]" type="text">
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You are asking for help? Because "I want this in jquery" sounds like a boss talking to an employee. Maybe you could try do it your self first and post your code here, so we can start from there and guide you.

Comment: May be you sound it negative. But i didnt mean that. Anyways thank you for your time.

Comment: For YOU, i removed that line "I want this in jquery'...

Comment: Anyone to help me on this Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go, now it's your task to refactoring the code because both methods are equals.

```js
var ProcessTable = (function () {
 
  var _slabs, _partsNumber;
  
  var _init = function () {
   _slabs = $('input[name^="slab_range"]');
    _partsNumber = $('input[name^="item_partno"]');
    
   _slabs.on('blur', _slabBlurHandler);
    _partsNumber.on('blur', _partNumberBlurHandler);
  };
  
  var _slabBlurHandler = function (e) {
   var value = $.trim($(this).val());
    
    if (value !== '') {
     _slabs.val('No bid');
    } else {
     _slabs.val('');
    }
    
    $(this).val(value); // Because the previous line override the original value
  };
  
  var _partNumberBlurHandler = function (e) {
    var value = $.trim($(this).val());
    
    if (value !== '') {
     _partsNumber.val('2');
    } else {
     _partsNumber.val('');
    }
    
     $(this).val(value); // Because the previous line override the original value
  };
  
  return {
   init: _init
  }
})();

ProcessTable.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cart1" name="cart" method="post" class="single" action="price_edit_save.php?supplier_name=Jupiter+Microwave+Components+Inc&amp;tender_id=151501">

 <div class="clone_row">
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
   <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
     <th width="4%">SlNo</th>
     <th width="4%">Slab Range</th>
     <th width="6%">Part Number</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input size="1" name="id[0]" value="9978" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">
      <input size="1" id="sl[0]" name="sl[0]" value="1" type="text">
      <input size="1" id="item_id[0]" name="item_id[0]" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input size="9" data-validation="required" name="slab_range[]" id="slab_range[]" type="text">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input size="9" name="item_partno[]" id="item_partno[]" type="text">
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input size="1" name="id[1]" value="9979" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">
      <input size="1" id="sl[1]" name="sl[1]" value="2" type="text">
      <input size="1" id="item_id[1]" name="item_id[1]" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input size="9" data-validation="required" name="slab_range[]" id="slab_range[]" type="text">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input size="9" name="item_partno[]" id="item_partno[]"  type="text">
     </td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
     <td>
      <input size="1" name="id[1]" value="9979" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">
      <input size="1" id="sl[1]" name="sl[1]" value="2" type="text">
      <input size="1" id="item_id[1]" name="item_id[1]" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input size="9" data-validation="required" name="slab_range[]" id="slab_range[]" type="text">
     </td>
     <td>
      <input size="9" name="item_partno[]" id="item_partno[]"  type="text">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>

 <div class="addMoreDIV">
  &nbsp;</div>

 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input value="--Update Data--" type="submit">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

And please, be more kindly when you ask for "help".

Comment: Thank you. Iam kind enough always. But at times when we type the language changes..Never mind..Basically iam good like you:) . Thank you so much for your time...